# Odd blackening of exterior on romex

Tags: electrical

I am adding some electrical in an old house that I just bought. The weird thing is that some of the romex is blackened and has some of the exterior sheathing gone. But that seems to be more from sloppy initial wiring. It’s weird because the internal wires do not appear to be bubbled out or singed in any way. There used to be some cloth wiring so maybe it is from old issues?  Ultimately I’m not sure if I need to spend the time and re-run wires, wrap the exposed sheathing for re-adding security, or just snip the wires and add a junction to run new wires to the box (the black is all at the last feet before the sub panel)? Could it also be from putting too many wires through a hole?  Pictures below:

[image: too many in one hole maybe]
[image: exposed but not bubbled]
[image: maybe gauge wrong]
[image: maybe something near box itself but not much]
[image: only seems to be on the outside]

Comment: The missing sections are from mice chewing.  The black I think is more old dirt/dust/something, but might be from heat(from the wires).  If scratched with a finger nail, does the black come off or does go deep?

Comment: Note that the filth **stops** at the hole (in the last picture) so it's certainly not wire charring from too many in the hole, though it could be soot from some *other* fire, or mold, or dirt/dust stuck to mouse urine. The chewing is why I ended up doing all my wiring in metallic conduit *a la* Chicago even though local code is fine with NM/B

Comment: I suspect that some of the darkening of the cable jacket is due to floor stain or some such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Romex has a finite service life

And that stuff doesn't "owe you anything" lol.

The rat-chewed stuff is also a good case for AC or MC cable, or metal conduit.